# CCS IMAGE SIZE is not effecting

Tags: html, css, image, size

I am facing a problem the size of image displaying on my page. The following CSS is not controlling it. It should look like a small image of products but the image is far bigger and i do not know what mistake i am making. please help.I am following a video tutorial, on his size everything work fine. Thanks.

```
<!--Products-->
<section class="products">
    <div class="section-title">
        <h2>Our products</h2>
    </div>
<div class="products-center">
    <!--Single Product-->
    <article class="product">

        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="./images/product-1.jpeg" alt="product" class="product-img">
            <button class="bag-btn" data-id="1">
               <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
               add to bag
            </button>

        </div>
        <h3>queen bed</h3>
        <h4>$100</h4>

    </article>

    <!--End of Singe Product-->


</div>


</section>

 
    <!--End of prodcuts-->
.products {
  padding: 4rem 0;
}
.section-title h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: var(--mainSpacing);
}
.products-center {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bag-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right: 0;
  background: var(--primaryColor);
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: var(--mainSpacing);
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
  transform: translateX(101%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bag-btn:hover {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
}
.fa-shopping-cart {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.img-container:hover .bag-btn {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.product-img {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  min-height: 12rem;
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
}
.img-container:hover .product-img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.product h3 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: var(--mainSpacing);
  text-align: center;
}

 .product h4 {
  margin-top: 0.7rem;
  letter-spacing: var(--mainSpacing);
  color: var(--primaryColor);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure if all the code is in one file or in separate files, but make sure that if the CSS is inside of the HTML page, use the <style></style> tags to store the CSS within them. P.S. I would personally recommended using pixels for height and width like this: width:100px;height:100px;

Comment: @Nooby427 it's not a good recommentation to use pixels for image size, think about responsive.....

Comment: This code is in separate file. I am using external CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

product-img width is using the total width of the parent element. Try setting that parent element width or change width: 100% to non % value. Example:

```
.img-container {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 200px; // This
}

.product-img {
 display: block;
 width:100%;
 min-height: 12rem;
 transition: var(--mainTransition);
}
```

Comment: i tried image size is now control after changing the width:20% but the products are showing top to bottom not left to right ... everytime i add an image product its show me vertically.

Comment: I can't replicate your code now. But maybe you should define a specific width to "product" class and set it as display: inline-block. By not doing so, each article will always take 100% width as default.